# BCP -K with SQL Server 2012 Always on listeners

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been trying to re-direct some `BCP` export processes to a secondary read-only SQL Server 2012 replica, but can't get it to redirect.

Below is an example of a test I've been running:

```
bcp "select * from <Table_Name>" queryout <File_Name>.csv -t \t -r ^|~^| -c -T –S <Listener> -e -K ReadOnly
```

The `BCP` runs ok, but on the primary replica not the read only secondary.

I've tested `ApplicationIntent=readOnly` with other connections and these are being re-directed, so its working for other processes, just not `BCP`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer - you need to add the -d  parameter, otherwise you default connection is going in all likelihood be to master, and that isn't part of the HA Group.

Adding the -d parm specifically connects you to your HA group DB, so then the -K parameter works.

Many thanks to Perry Whittle for pointing this out.

Cheers

Roop